# Hiding Mobile Content for Outlook using MSO 9 condition

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am building an email template and have come across a situation where I want to hide a 'td' on desktop. I was able to achieve it using media queries and "display":none" property for almost all email clients except for Outlook 2007/10/13/16.

My 'td' looks something like this.

```
                        <td style="display:none;" class="show" >
                <table border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="usual styling">
                            <font>some text</font>
                        </td>                  
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
```

and show class is as simple as:

```
            /* Responsive */ 
        @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
            .show {display:inline !important;}
            }
```

I read in different forums that there using mso 9 if condition, you can keep part of HTML hidden from Outlook. So I tried something like:

```
 <!--[if !mso 9]><\!-->
<td style="display:none;" class="show" >
    <table border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="usual styling">
            <font>some text</font>
            </td>                  
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

But Outlook 2007/10/13/16 still show this  and content inside it. Can someone help me figure out how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<td style="display:none;" class="show" >
  <table border="0"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="usual styling">
        <font>some texty</font>
      </td>                  
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
<![endif]-->
```

Here's some other information that could help you with Outlook.

Microsoft Outlook ignores @media queries.

In your code you have a class called `.show`. If you want to hide a class from Outlook, create a style sheet, place it in the `<head>` just below your other `<style>` sheet. That should make it behave.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .show {display:none;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck.